# 100% width pseudo elements don't match the width of parent when in a justified text line

Tags: html, css, firefox, justify

As you can see in the example, when setting the width of an absolute positioned pseudo element works find normally, but if it's within an element with `text-align: justify` set, the pseudo element seems to be the width that the parent element would be if justify were not set.

This is evident by it not happening on links outside the paragraph, or on the last line where the text is not justified.

Anyone know how to avoid this?

It appears to only happen in Firefox, not Chrome. Any ideas for a workaround?

I found this bug report on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1262910).

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc
}

.test::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  width: 300px; margin: auto;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="test">how it should look</a>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#" class="test">i am text</a> consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique tristique sem at molestie. Maecenas eget lacus est.  <a href="#" class="test">i am text</a> Aenean leo eros, eleifend id blandit sit amet, feugiat sit amet velit. Quisque  <a href="#" class="test">i am text</a> mattis at diam et vulputate. Pellentesque vitae nisi lacinia, tempus lorem in, dapibus sem. Phasellus auctor urna risus, eu tempus enim scelerisque at. Proin at nunc quis tellus  <a href="#" class="test">i am text</a> ultricies faucibus quis eu risus. Donec hendrerit venenatis orci vitae aliquet. Praesent pretium sodales nisl, id commodo nisl accumsan ac.  <a href="#" class="test">i am text</a> </p>
```

Comment: Fast trial: Add `display: inline-block` in your `.test` class. Side effect: the text inside your <a> won't follow the justify text property (p will).